# Boxplot with ggplot2: Trying to lay geom_jitter over code for plot, strange outlier dots

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

There a two different codes I researched and am using for making boxplots for my data:

One code (A) is fairly simple, and essentially shows the features I would like in my boxplot: gridlines in the back, distinguishing of my patient groups in control and intervention and by visit, a scaling with numbers on the x and y axis. One problem is that there are weird outliers shown, which I would rather just incorporate into a jitter, where all data points are shown. I would also like to change the measurements of the plot a little, i.e. the x and y axis length/ratios to a more square shape and it would be ideal, if the control and intervention boxes could be further apart from one another. I would also stylistically would like to fill the boxes with a lighter color, as shown in "B".

Thank you in advance!

This is the code for A:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=visit,y=weight_v1_3, color=groupci)) +
  geom_boxplot(width=.5) + theme_bw() + scale_color_brewer(palette="Dark2")
```

The second code I am using (B) has a geom_jitter, which I would really like to incorporate into A.

The code for B:

```
  df <- df %>% 
  rename_with(~ gsub("\\.", "_", tolower(.x))) 

pal <- c("red", "blue")

g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = groupci, y = weight_v1_3)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = groupci, fill = after_scale
(colorspace::lighten(fill, .7))), alpha = .5, size = 1.5, outlier.size = 5)
  

g + 
  geom_jitter(aes(color = groupci), width = .1, size = 7, alpha = .5) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1:9) +
  scale_color_manual(values = pal, guide = "none") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = pal, guide = "none")
```

Sample data:

```
structure(list(pseudonym = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), control.0.1. = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), intervention.0.1. = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), visit = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), weight.V1.3 = c(60L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 
59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 57L, 
57L, 57L, 57L, 57L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-31L))
```

"A" plot:

[image: A plot]

"B" plot:

[image: B plot]

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing the outlier points because by default, they are shown in `geom_boxplot()`.  If you would prefer to hide them, you can set `outlier.color` or `outlier.shape` to `NA` within `geom_boxplot()`.

Here's an illustrative example.  First, showing boxplots overlaying `geom_jitter()` with default values.  The color of the box plot is black and I've changed the shape of the jitter points to make the outlier points shown via `geom_boxplot()` more apparent.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- diamonds[sample(1:nrow(diamonds), size=500),]

p <-
ggplot(df, aes(x=cut, y=price)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  geom_jitter(aes(color=cut), width=0.2, size=2, shape=2)
p
```

[image]

Now, to remove the outliers from the boxplot geom, you can set any of the `outlier.shape` or `outlier.color` values to `NA` and it will remove them.

```
p1 <-
ggplot(df, aes(x=cut, y=price)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(color=cut), width=0.2, size=2, shape=2)
p1
```

[image]

You should be able to apply this to your own example (I could not reproduce because you reference columns in the code that do not exist in the data); however, note that removing outliers *does not work with `outlier.size=NA`*.  You'll have to use `outlier.color=NA` or `outlier.shape=NA`.